# How to display string from class Person

Tags: asp.net, json

I've been looking into JSON, and classes.

The example 1 from the [LINK HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Using Example 1 code, how would I display all the results, the strings?

Regards
Blanco

Comment: Use [JSON.Net Library](http://james.newtonking.com/json) for better performance

Comment: I'm new to classes and JSON etc.  tried nothing, need a simple solution.

Comment: I assume I just create an Object of person?  Then display the properties?